# Tensorflow Object Detection Api TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Then i try to train model with

```
  python3 model_main.py —logtostderr —train_dir=training/ —pipelnie_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

i got following error. All configurations are setted up. Firstly i tried it on Mac and it's worked. But the training process took so long on cpu i decided to go on cloud computing with GPU(paperspace). I did everything exact the same and got this error. All files are presented. What could i did wrong? It's seems something wrong with configuration file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "model_main.py", line 71, in main
FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
File "/home/paperspace/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 589, in create_estimator_and_inputs
pipeline_config_path, config_override=config_override)
File "/home/paperspace/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 97, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
proto_str = f.read()
File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
self._preread_check()
File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 61, in as_bytes
(bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None
```

Config file:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 1100
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Comment: The error trace said your config file path was not correctly set. The error was caused in function `get_configs_from_pipeline_file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in your command.
It should be

```
pipeline_config_path
```

instead of

```
pipelnie_config_path
```

Also if you run with `model_main.py`, is the argument `--model_dir` instead of `-train_dir`, with double dashes?